# Getting this error message when trying to UPDATE MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

> Notice: Undefined variable: table_name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/welcometowarwick/scripts/php/insert_imagery.php on line 106
>   Error: UPDATE SET business_description='', image1='profiles/sadsadas/', image2='profiles/sadsadas/', image3='profiles/sadsadas/', image4='profiles/sadsadas/', image5='profiles/sadsadas/' WHERE id='307' LIMIT 1
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET business_description='', image1='profiles/sadsadas/', image2='pr' at line 1

Here is the UPDATE code

```
$updatesql = sprintf("UPDATE $table_name SET
business_description='$business_description',
image1='$insert_upload1',
image2='$insert_upload2',
image3='$insert_upload3',
image4='$insert_upload4',
image5='$insert_upload5'



WHERE id='$user_id' LIMIT 1");  

if (mysqli_query($link, $updatesql)) {
    header('Location: ../../register/complete.php');



} else {
    echo "Error: " . $updatesql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Can anyone see what the error with the syntax is?

Comment: Exactly what's not clear about that errorr? What are the contents of `$table_name` ?

Comment: try to hard-code table name directly and check once. the error states that your table_name is either not created or not defined(assigned with any value). Please check it also that $table_name is having nay value or not and is it created or not?

Comment: var_dump($updatesql) and see if is a valid query.

Comment: plus why `sprintf`? you don't have any `sprintf` statements. http://php.net/sprintf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, therefore I am submitting the following.

The syntax error is clear:

`right syntax to use near 'SET` it starts at `SET`, so this tells me that:

- `$table_name` is either not defined, or it contains a character that MySQL doesn't agree with. Possibly a space, a hyphen; who knows. Only you know that and how `$table_name` is defined, or whether it's defined at all.
- Plus, as I stated in comments; you're using [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) but there is no syntax to support that. You can just get rid of it, far as I'm concerned.

It is also unclear which MySQL API you are using to connect with, so make sure you are indeed using `mysqli_` to connect with and not `mysql_` or PDO.

- Those different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other.

If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to place a comment underneath my answer.

You may also want to make use of [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) in order to escape your data. There might be characters in there that MySQL will also want to buck about.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score -1):

this query can't get the table name so it happens try to first echo $updatesql and check the query get table name

Comment: that's not my downvote but it's already been stated in comments. Someone probably gave you that because they found it was just that; fit as a comment. You may want to elaborate on that, and look at their code again, including a comment I left about their use of `sprintf`.